# How can i make a generated code using fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, pdf-generation, fpdf

This code was made by other, but i want to change it for my own purposes.
The code is giving 13 numbers, but only want the numbers of the ID(from database).

Example of what i need:

- ID = 908
- EAN13 = 000000908

My real question is how can i remove the 0000 from the BARS, then after scanning the SCANNER wil read the correct ID.
This is fora study guys!

```
class PDF_BARCODE extends FPDF
{
function EAN13($x, $y, $barcode, $h=16, $w=.35, $fSize=9)
{
    $this->Barcode($x,$y,$barcode,$h,$w,$fSize,13);
}

function UPC_A($x, $y, $barcode, $h=16, $w=.35, $fSize=9)
{
    $this->Barcode($x,$y,$barcode,$h,$w,$fSize,12);
}

function GetCheckDigit($barcode)
{
    //Compute the check digit
    $sum=0;
    for($i=1;$i<=11;$i+=2)
        $sum+=3*$barcode[$i];
    for($i=0;$i<=10;$i+=2)
        $sum+=$barcode[$i];
    $r=$sum%10;
    if($r>0)
        $r=10-$r;
    return $r;
}

function TestCheckDigit($barcode)
{
    //Test validity of check digit
    $sum=0;
    for($i=1;$i<=11;$i+=2)
        $sum+=3*$barcode[$i];
    for($i=0;$i<=10;$i+=2)
        $sum+=$barcode[$i];
    return ($sum+$barcode[12])%10==0;
}

function Barcode($x, $y, $barcode, $h, $w, $fSize, $len)
{
    //Padding
    $barcode=str_pad($barcode,$len-1,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if($len==12)
        $barcode='0'.$barcode;
    //Add or control the check digit
    if(strlen($barcode)==12)
        $barcode.=$this->GetCheckDigit($barcode);
    elseif(!$this->TestCheckDigit($barcode))
        $this->Error('Incorrect check digit');
    //Convert digits to bars
    $codes=array(
        'A'=>array(
            '0'=>'0001101','1'=>'0011001','2'=>'0010011','3'=>'0111101','4'=>'0100011',
            '5'=>'0110001','6'=>'0101111','7'=>'0111011','8'=>'0110111','9'=>'0001011'),
        'B'=>array(
            '0'=>'0100111','1'=>'0110011','2'=>'0011011','3'=>'0100001','4'=>'0011101',
            '5'=>'0111001','6'=>'0000101','7'=>'0010001','8'=>'0001001','9'=>'0010111'),
        'C'=>array(
            '0'=>'1110010','1'=>'1100110','2'=>'1101100','3'=>'1000010','4'=>'1011100',
            '5'=>'1001110','6'=>'1010000','7'=>'1000100','8'=>'1001000','9'=>'1110100')
        );
    $parities=array(
        '0'=>array('A','A','A','A','A','A'),
        '1'=>array('A','A','B','A','B','B'),
        '2'=>array('A','A','B','B','A','B'),
        '3'=>array('A','A','B','B','B','A'),
        '4'=>array('A','B','A','A','B','B'),
        '5'=>array('A','B','B','A','A','B'),
        '6'=>array('A','B','B','B','A','A'),
        '7'=>array('A','B','A','B','A','B'),
        '8'=>array('A','B','A','B','B','A'),
        '9'=>array('A','B','B','A','B','A')
        );
    $code='101';
    $p=$parities[$barcode[0]];
    for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++)
        $code.=$codes[$p[$i-1]][$barcode[$i]];
    $code.='01010';
    for($i=7;$i<=12;$i++)
        $code.=$codes['C'][$barcode[$i]];
    $code.='101';
    //Draw bars
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($code);$i++)
    {
        if($code[$i]=='1')
            $this->Rect($x+$i*$w,$y,$w,$h,'F');
    }
    //Print text uder barcode
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',$fSize);
    $this->Text($x,$y+$h+11/$this->k,substr($barcode,-$len));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [EAN-13 barcode format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number#EAN-13_barcode_example) inherently encodes 13 digits. If you mess with it so it encodes fewer digits, the barcode will no longer be EAN-13, and many barcode readers will not recognize it.

You're using leading zeros on your codes in your nonstandard application. I say nonstandard because EAN-13 has a registry of prefixes.  Whatever you use to read your barcodes will need to remove the leading zeros.

If you must avoid leading zeros in your barcode, you may want to switch to another more flexible barcode format, Code 39, Codabar, or even QR codes. Or you might choose EAN-8 or EAN-5. You can look up all these.

Comment: That's the problem, i'm not reading zeros.. its onlye the spefici ID with 7 characters.